# How do I deploy System.Management.Automation?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am helping out with a project that a contractor worked on previously (so I don't have a lot of history for it).

The project builds fine, but when we try to perform some operations, we get a runtime error indicating that System.Management.Automation.dll could not be found.

As a troublshooting measure, we manually installed the dll into the installation directory.  We then get an error indicating failure to load Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.

As nearly as I can tell, these dlls are present in the Microsoft Management Framework download, and possibly in Powershell 3.0.

My question:  What is the smallest package that these dlls are a part of, and what is the best way to deploy them for a production software release?

**Edit**

Just to be clear -- I am not looking to hack/frankenbuild by deploying just those dlls "naked", I am trying to identify the correct redistributable package for those dlls.  I just can't seem to work out which one it is.

**Edit**

If it helps, the nature of the code that we are running is to programmatically create an exchange mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't legally redistribute any of those two DLLs alone (discussed for example **[here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/383e503e-89f4-4c72-b0da-1874bf9565ff)** for the Automation, you can also check the "Redistributable" **[section on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.management.infrastructure%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** for those namespaces). You will have to make sure the target machines have PowerShell and the Management Framework.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to redistribute them alone -- I'm trying to identify the correct redistributable package to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem: We ended up resolving the issue by deploying the Windows Management Framework 3.0, which includes the necessary assemblies. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595